# jquery/javascript code to click an id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to test some jquery/javascript code from chrome console
so when i am on a website to click all the elements which have the id="test"

So im trying the codes

```
    function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("test").click();
}
```

or

```
$('#test').click();
```

But nothing is working.
What am i doing wrong???

html code.

```
<a id="test" target="_blank" href="www.stackoverflow.com"><img src="https://appharbor.com/assets/images/stackoverflow-logo.png" border="0" width="300" class="test_img" onload=""></a>
```

Comment: ID must be unique  use class instead

Comment: $('#test').click(function(){<write code here>});

Comment: You can't have multiple **ID** use **class** instead.

Comment: Also make sure your page is done loading or jquery will not find your element : $(document).ready(function(){ ...insert your js here... });

Comment: @LaurentFauvel yeap is done loading.

Comment: @jlocker its not my page so i am trying to make something with "id"

Comment: @LuckyChingi what kind of code should i write there? i only want to push the button.

Comment: What do you want to happen on click?

Comment: @NenadVracar to transfer me to the href link

Comment: Why are you using js for that?

Comment: @NenadVracar what should i use?

Comment: Try this `<a href="linkWhereYouWantToGo.html"><img src="someImg.png" alt=""></a>` you don't need js for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to activate an anchor link dynamically. This can't be achieved by simply triggering the click event via `$.click()`.

Try this:

```
window.location = $('#test').attr('href');
```

Same without jQuery:

```
window.location = document.getElementById('test').getAttribute('href');
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attr' of null... when i run your code.

Comment: That means jquery doesn't find the element specified. Try `$(window).load(function(){window.location = $('#test').attr('href');});`

Comment: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '[object Window]' is not a valid selector.

Comment: There's something weird going on with jquery on your site. Try the version without jquery. (edited my answer)

Comment: does it matter that its in an iframe?

Comment: depends on what you mean by that. You can't access the iframe DOM via javascript from the parent document.

Comment: and how can i access iframe from chrome console ?? the iframe has an id="test2"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93293/discussion-between-kwnstantinos-natsios-and-anttiviljami).

Comment: You can access the iframe element with regular selectors, but you can't access anything inside it. This is for security reasons.

Comment: Iframe can not be accessed from outside, wich mean your js need to be inside the iframe if you want to interact with the content inside it. That is why your jquery can not find any element with an id=test.

Comment: after a discussion on chat we actually cant access iframe for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to push the button try the bellow,

Use [Trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) function

```js
$("#test").trigger("click");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="test" target="_blank" href="www.stackoverflow.com"><img src="https://appharbor.com/assets/images/stackoverflow-logo.png" border="0" width="300" class="test_img" onload=""></a>
```

Comment: Nope its not working cause it is on an iframe and i cant access it.

Comment: if it's on iframe you can't access it due to the cross domain issue